# Nodejs mssql connection error tls.createSecurePair() is deprecated. Please use tls.Socket instead

Tags: sql-server, node.js, database-connection

I am moving my nodejs application from local to web server. 
When I test the DB connection(SQL Server using '**mssql**' package) on my local machine, the connection is successful, but on the webserver I get the error message:

```
<node:6316> [DEP0064] DeprecationWarning: tls.createSecurePair() is deprecated. 
Please use tls.Socket() instead.
```

The only difference I can think of is my local server npm version is 2.15.5 and web server npm version is 5.6.0.
Do I need to install an old version of nodejs to make it work or there could be some way to make it work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?  I have the same issue when deploying on Azure.  Azure doesnot allow the App to start and prints the Warning as stderr in Logs.

Answer (score 2):

This warning actually comes from the underlying TDS driver (see https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/issues/515), and is currently (as of early 2018) receiving attention and attempts to resolve.  It should also be noted that according to https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/17882 the `tls.createSecurePair()` API will remain in Node 8 which is now LTS until the end of 2019.

Furthermore, this is just a warning, but the functionality is still there.  If you `tcpdump` port 1433 you'll see that your connection is encrypted if you are using the `encrypt` option.

Comment: It is a warning, but it is not allowing the Azure Web App to start the server, it displays the warning as stderr in Logs.  How could it be resolved? :/

Comment: @CoderX, Were you able to get this working? I am also stuck with same issue here